# How Can I Show the Picture After Merging the Array?

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

I have a post.I'm making an array explode this post.I have two rules when explode the post.

**First Rule:** The target must be between a tag.

**Second Rule:** The words must be explode down according to the space between them.

There is no problem up to this point.You can see it from the code below.

```
$demo = '<p>This is a red image.Red images do not look good under natural light.This is due to the 
saturation rates.
<info><a href="http://localhost/img/red_image.jpg"><img class="danger_image" 
src="http://localhost/img/red_image.jpg" alt="red_image_info"/></a>
</info></p>';

$demo = str_replace("<info", "*<info", $demo);
$demo = str_replace("</info>", "</info>*", $demo);
$new_array = array();
foreach (explode('*', $demo) as $demo_loop) {
  $new_array[] = explode(' ', $demo_loop);
}

echo '<pre>';
 print_r($new_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

While doing the joining process, I place comment lines between the words.The problem arises after implode the array.

```
implode(" <!--test--> ",$new_array[$i][$is]);
```

I complete this implode in a loop.The picture is not displayed while the text is displayed normally.

The output is like this:

> This is a red image.Red images do not look good under natural light.This is due to the saturation 
>     rates.
>     href="http://localhost/img/red_image.jpg"> class="danger_image" 
>     src="http://localhost/img/red_image.jpg" alt="red_image_info"/>

As a result of my experiments, I found that the comments lines caused this.If I can delete these comment lines inside the target tag, I will succeed what I want.

But I got stuck at this point

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the "in_array" function? Maybe you can distinguish this way.

```
if (in_array("<info>", $new_array)) {
  echo "Found! -> Delete Comment Lines";
}else {
  echo "Not Found!";
}
```

You can then delete the comment lines for arrays that do not meet the condition.Remember that this is just an idea.

Comment: I have tried this method before.But it didn't work as I wanted.I am trying to loop the merged array again.So I can clear the comment lines of the text between the target tags. As a result, I got into a dead end.